# Can't change Value/dimens because 2 phones are to close in dpi and resolutin

Tags: android

I have a Galaxy Nexus and a Droid Maxx, both are the same resolutions and really close DPI, I'm trying to move a ImageView a certain dp based on the size of the device because for example:
If I set marginTop="10dp" on the Nexus that's huge amount and on the Maxx its not enough. I need these to match but using the alternative values folders doesn't work because the screen sizes are to close.

Comment: Main problem of xml layouts, create your ui at code with pixel perfect sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new `values` directories with `values-h***dp` qualifier, for example, `values-h1024dp`, `values-h720dp`, and declare different `dimens.xml` in these directories. In this case if the height of the screen is closer to 720dp, then the `dimens.xml` from `values-h720dp` will be applied, if the height is closer to 1024dp, then `dimens.xml` from `values-h1024dp`will be used.
Here you can read more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html (Available height) 
Usually this technique is applied to the width, not to the height, but height is also OK.

Comment: Ive tried what you stated above and it makes my app crash on start. Also since both phones are the same resolution and DPI just different physical sizes, wouldn't that not work anyway?

Comment: You have to keep `values` folder (without a qualifier) with default values. Do you? If it isn't the reason, then nothing can be told without a log.

Comment: @user2555459, if the resolution is the same in pixels, not in `dp`-s, this may work.